# C# regex to find all spaces which are not behind a specified word

Tags: c#, regex

i'm having trouble to create a .net-regex which finds all spaces which are not behind the word pi.

This is the given string `"y + pi + s + 1 = x"`

I tried `"(?!pi\s)\s"` but it finds every space and didn't exclude the one after "pi".
I used [.Net Regey Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe [`\s+(?!pi\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b(%3f!pi%5cb)&i=y+%2b+pi+%2b+s+%2b+1+%3d+x)? Or maybe even [`(?>\s+)(?!pi\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3e%5cs%2b)(%3f!pi%5cb)&i=y+%2b+++pi+%2b+s+%2b+1+%3d+x)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide expected string result and the current failed string result

Comment: @VisualVincent: That is why I do not post an answer - it is unclear. *finds all spaces which are not behind the word pi* != *didn't exclude the one after "pi"*. What is **behind**?

Comment: "Finds all spaces which are not behind the word 'pi'" seems straightforward to me. I'm not sure what you guys are complaining about.

Comment: @Wiktor : Perhaps he meant _behind_ like this: "pi **(space)**"? I don't know. :)

Comment: @Colin: There is left and right here, and "behind" (as in lookbehind) means *to the left*. At least that is how I see it.

Comment: @Colin : Because it's not clear what he asks. At first he says "**(behind)** pi" then he says "pi **(after)**". **Behind** = _left side_, **After** = _right side_.

Comment: Maybe it's a cultural thing, but I naturally read "behind" as being "after". Granted, "behind" means something different in Regex, but that's because of the context of a search that has already traversed the text on the left.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your regex is that it's effectively looking for a double-space*: the `\s` in the look-behind makes it "a space preceded by `'p'`, `'i'`, `''`, not simply a space preceded by `'p'`, `'i'`

The fix is straightforward - remove `\s` from the lookbehind:

```
(?<!pi)\s
```

Note that this regex would skip spaces preceded by longer words ending in `pi` as well, such as `Principi`. If you do not want these matches, add `\b` in front of `pi`:

```
(?<!\bpi)\s
```

* Note that your syntax for lookbehind wasn't correct because of missing `<`. I assume it was a typo.

Comment: He also wasn't using negative look-behind (he was using negative look-ahead)

Comment: @RobertMcKee That's a fair observation, too. I automatically corrected it, assuming it was a typo, but you are right, the syntax in the question is not correct.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - nevermind. I'm an idiot. :-D I just got my wires crossed.

Comment: Ha! Actually I wasn't crazy then. I think I posted the expression a little before yours came in, but that's the way things go on SO. I'm joking around though, totally ribbing you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\bpi)\s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Works like a charm. I'm going to work through the text.